# adding empty months to array when grouping by month

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, group-by

I'm trying to count the number of records in the database for each month. But there's months that don't have any records, and I'd like to add those to my array as well

```
@activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
records_by_month = @activity.records.max_12_months.group_by{ |t| t.happened.beginning_of_month }
hori = Array.new
verti = Array.new
records_by_month.sort.each do |month, recs|
  hori.push(month.strftime('%B'))
  verti.push(recs.count)
end
```

This is what records_by_month looks like:

```
#<OrderedHash {Tue, 01 Jan 2013=>[#<Record id: 37, details: "",
happened: "2013-01-09", duration: nil, activity_id: 21, created_at: "2013-04-11 14:31:30",
updated_at: "2013-04-11 14:31:30", price: 15.0>], Fri, 01 Mar 2013=>
[#<Record id: 36, details: "", happened: "2013-03-04", duration: nil,
activity_id: 21, created_at: "2013-04-11 14:31:12", updated_at: "2013-04-11 14:31:12", price: 15.0>],
Thu, 01 Nov 2012=>[#<Record id: 38, details: "", happened: "2012-11-29",
duration: nil, activity_id: 21, created_at: "2013-04-11 14:31:51",
updated_at: "2013-04-11 14:31:51", price: 15.0>]}>
```

Any idea how I can add the month name to hori, and 0 to verti for each month that has no records?

Comment: can you give the output of `records_by_month` line?

Comment: why you want to add `0` ? need that information.

Comment: Because I want to plot the number of records per month in a graph

Comment: I have given a code,please check if it helpful for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok (slightly changed for testing) ... how about something like this?

```
ALL = [%w{
  January February March
  April   May      June
  July    August   September
  October November December
}, [0] * 12].transpose
hori = Hash[ALL]
verti = Hash[ALL]
{'January' => 1, 'March' => 5}.each do |month, recs|
  hori[month] = :test
  verti[month] = recs
end
p hori.sort.map(&:last)  # => [0, 0, 0, 0, :test, 0, 0, :test, 0, 0, 0, 0]
p verti.sort.map(&:last) # => [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Could you add some comments to what exactly is happening please? I'm guessing I should replace `{'January' => 1, 'March' => 5}` with `records_by_month` but I don't understand the code very well.

Comment: You are correct. The idea is that it's easy to make a Hash with each month as a key. The `[0] * 12` and `.transpose` just adds a value of any sort (in this case 0) after every month, it's exactly the same as writing: `{ 'January' => 0, 'February' => 0, ...}`. Since we are constructing Hash objects instead of arrays, we don't need to sort `records_by_month` and after the values for the available keys are set (for `horti` and `verti`) it only remains to drop the keys by mapping each hash (actually, after the sort they are Arrays) with `element.last` via Symbol's #to_proc instance method. (:last)

Comment: So yes, you need to replace `{ ... }` with `records_by_month`, and you probably also have to extract the real month string out of the block parameter `month`, and change the assignments a little.

Comment: This works pretty well but for a graph it would make more sense if the current month is the last one on the list. Any idea how I could set them in the right order?

Comment: I actually assumed that they were ordered starting from January but in that case `1`should be first and `5` should be third. And I don't see why there's two zero's between 1 and 5 when there's only one month between January and March.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hints for your problem,not the full solution:

```
require 'date'

h = {"Tue, 01 Jan 2013" =>[Record_id: 37, details: "",
happened: "2013-01-09", duration: nil, activity_id: 21, created_at: "2013-04-11 14:31:30",
updated_at: "2013-04-11 14:31:30", price: 15.0], "Fri, 01 Mar 2013" =>
[Record_id: 36, details: "", happened: "2013-03-04", duration: nil,
activity_id: 21, created_at: "2013-04-11 14:31:12", updated_at: "2013-04-11 14:31:12", price: 15.0],
"Thu, 01 Nov 2012" =>[Record_id: 38, details: "", happened: "2012-11-29",
duration: nil, activity_id: 21, created_at: "2013-04-11 14:31:51",
updated_at: "2013-04-11 14:31:51", price: 15.0]}

hori = {}
verti = {}

h.each {|k,v| hori[Date.parse(k).strftime('%B')] = v}
p hori

Date::MONTHNAMES.compact.map {|m| verti[m]=0 unless hori.keys.include? m}
p verti
```

*Output:*

```
{"January"=>[{:Record_id=>37, :details=>"", :happened=>"2013-01-09", :duration=>nil, :activity_id=>21, :created_at=>"2013-04-11 14:31:30", :updated_at=>"2013-04-11 14:31:30", :price=>15.0}], "March"=>[{:Record_id=>36, :details=>"", :happened=>"2013-03-04", :duration=>nil, :activity_id=>21, :created_at=>"2013-04-11 14:31:12", :updated_at=>"2013-04-11 14:31:12", :price=>15.0}], "November"=>[{:Record_id=>38, :details=>"", :happened=>"2012-11-29", :duration=>nil, :activity_id=>21, :created_at=>"2013-04-11 14:31:51", :updated_at=>"2013-04-11 14:31:51", :price=>15.0}]}

{"February"=>0, "April"=>0, "May"=>0, "June"=>0, "July"=>0, "August"=>0, "September"=>0, "October"=>0, "December"=>0}
```